# Title not wrapping in Custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]Bigger title aligns left in recent post by categories.

This is code, which i am getting issue. I have added a image also.

```
<div class="clearfix shadow-sm bg-white rounded">

<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=10&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array (75, 75), array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?></a>
<?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<div class="cat-title font-weight-bold">
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

And I have aligned image as inline

```
.clearfix h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Please help to wrap the title correctly.

Comment: `.clearfix h2, .clearfix h3, .clearfix h4, .clearfix h5 {}`

Comment: It's working in Firefox, not in chrome.